# Url - a string, a double or something else

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Working on a spring, hibernate, and thymeleaf project.  I am trying to link a category image with a main item in a database that will have an image of the item attached to it.  What I think i need to do is create a category java class, a category repository java interface, and a categoryServiceImpl implementation java class in my service folder.  But that doesn't sound right to me.  I tried to add an additional MultipartFile categoryImage in my merchandise.java file and add the following code to my controller

Merchandise.java

```js
@Entity
public class Merchandise {
 
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
 private Long id;
 private String title;
 private String size;
 private String format;
 private String screenSize;
 private String category;
 private double shippingWeight;
 private double listPrice;
 private double salePrice;
 private boolean active=true;
 
 @Column(columnDefinition="text")
 private String description;
 private int inStockNumber;
 
 @Transient
 private MultipartFile merchImage;
    private MultipartFile categoryImage;
```

Controller

```js
@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addMerchandisePost(
  @ModelAttribute("merchandise") Merchandise merchandise, HttpServletRequest request) {
  merchandiseService.save(merchandise);

  MultipartFile merchImage = merchandise.getMerchImage();

  try {
    byte[] bytes = merchImage.getBytes();
    String name = merchandise.getId() + ".jpg";
    BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("src/main/resources/static/image/merch/" + name)));
    stream.write(bytes);
    stream.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  MultipartFile categoryImage = merchandise.getCategoryImage();

  try {
    byte[] bytes = categoryImage.getBytes();
    String name = merchandise.getId() + ".jpg";
    BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("src/main/resources/static/image/category/" + name)));
    stream.write(bytes);
    stream.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }

  return "redirect:merchandiseList";
}
```

But that didn't work.  I just end up getting the exception: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource.  I'm at a loss.

[image: hiarachy]

Comment: Post the stacktrace of error that you are getting

Answer (score 0):

Don't mid web content - MultipartFile and entity. In the entity there should be Blob field or byte[] wchih can be stored in DB and retrieved back. But actually you don't need it at all. Store instead a String - path to the file.

Don't use entity to get data in your controller. Instead create a DTO (Data Transfer Object) a plain old java object with all the fields you need to pass from UI.

BTW **exception: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource** is not related to the posted code at all. It is rather something wrong with your spring config.

Post full stack trace and your spring configs to say more.

Comment: When I remove the `private MultipartFile categoryImage` from the merchandise.java I don't get the error and server runs perfectly fine.  Its only when I add that, I get the exception.

Comment: Remove it from entity and create a separate DTO file with the MultipartFile  property.

Comment: Ok I'll see what I can do.  Extremely new at this so pretty much learning on the fly.  Also the reason I'm using entity is the udemy instructor pretty much said so but I've had a feeling the entire time ive been taking this course that some things didn't add up.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer pointed out, it is not suitable to store the image in DB as blob, but rather a file in filesystem and just store a path to that file as metadata in DB.
As for your error, you need to configure the multipart bean in your spring config class, the class that implements `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`

Put the below definition

```
// Bean name must be "multipartResolver", by default Spring uses method name
    // as bean name.
    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        return new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
    }
```

Add below imports

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartResolver;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver;
```

Comment: hmm...i've not created a class that implements the `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.  My security config extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` but those two are not the same.

Comment: I assume its a MVC setting, where have you configured your resource handlers? viewResolver etc, put the bean definition in same class.

Comment: added an image of my file hieararchy and I have no file that implements the MVC.

Comment: If you are using Thymeleaf 3, use this guide
http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/thymeleaf3migration.html
And the class there "ThymeleafConfig " can be used for your purpose , plus add the multipart  bean definition . If you are having trouble in getting started, i would suggest to read Spring in Action 4. It is very handy

Comment: Thanks i will take a look at both of those